# Inconsistent data return

Tags: excel, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

When using a query in Oracle SQL Developer there are X rows.

The basic query is:
`SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (t1.COL = t2.COL) WHERE t1.DATE <= '5-DEC-15' AND t1.GROUP IN ('A', 'B', 'C') ORDER BY t2.BRAND, t1.ORDER, t1.FACT;`

Rerunning this query every few minutes over a period of time results in X each time. Where X is equal to the previous X.

Creating an Excel data connection using this query and `Microsoft OLE DB Provider ODBC Drivers` creates very inconsistent data. Inconsistent in these terms is run the query and wait for the query to finish executing in full. This will create A rows in the Excel file. Immediately re-run the query the rows will be B. B and A do not equal each other and do not equal X. In fact `A & B < X`. There is no known relationship between A and B. (seemingly random..) The number of rows are currently in the 70-90K range.

Searching this issue lead me to this link:

> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E60419_01/epm.11125/readme/smart_view_11125200_readme.html

The listed item below seems to be a similar situation, but I have seen rows > 65,536. I think the highest I have noticed was 77000...ish.

> 17594115 -- In Excel 2013, attempting to refresh more than 65,536 rows in Smart View caused an Excel maximum rows and columns error.

I have attempted to limit the rows using `ROWNUM < Y` where Y is some number (ex. '10', '250', etc..), but at 10 the rows are always 10 long, but not always the same data. Rerunning the same limit in SQL Developer gives the same outcome as Excel. Running it at 100 or 250 or 500 acts the same as a 77000 row query (the issue stated above).

Officially, I haven't ruled any exact problems out because I don't have any solid evidence for or against any possibility. Has anyone seen this or have known documentation for this occurring?

Using::

32 bit Excel
32 bit Oracle Drivers
(I think) 64 bit Oracle Server
64 bit SQL Developer
64 bit Machine

(SQL Developer and Excel are not on the same machine as running 32 bit Oracle Drivers do not work in SQL Developer 64 bit client)

Comment: Do you really, genuinely need all those rows in a single Excel worksheet?

Comment: In this case yes. The report being run is currently being focused on in Excel. We are exploring other routes of using the data in something like Tableau, but the data for this specific report (and potentially many others) need to be complete.

Comment: I know this question is old, but did you find the answer to it? We are having a similar issue that sometimes (randomly) several records are missing (out of around 6000) when we retrieve the data from an Oracle 11g database into Excel 2019 using OLE DB connection.

Comment: @user2528260 No I didn't come to a solution for this particular issue. I convinced my team to move away from using this connection and got the data another way. Honestly, I came to the conclusion there is some disconnect for how the OLE DB connection pulls data. It seems it pulls some number of rows in a random order and then spits it back out with a maximum. That maximum was not constant, but seemed to be based on what the data was returning in some way. I don't know how true that is though.